# Possible concerns while using Redis replicas to serve read requests.

Tags: redis

Are there any concerns in using Redis replicas to serve read requests? Will updated data be available immediately? I know redis replication is asynchronous so I am wondering what kind of issues will I run into a setup that is configured to use a master for writes and master+replica for reads?

Answer (score 2):

There's no guarantee that data will fully replicated into the slave nodes, but that's not a problem in a lot of today's services. It depends on your particular use case if you can live with potential stale data.

You can configure the slaves so they only serve up-to-date data by setting this property on your slave configuration file:

```
slave-serve-stale-data yes
```

This bit of documentation might help clarify that it does in detail. Do take note that redis will not automatically fallback to an updated node, instead it reply with an error and you either try again or fallback to another node:

```
# When a slave loses its connection with the master, or when the replication
# is still in progress, the slave can act in two different ways:
#
# 1) if slave-serve-stale-data is set to 'yes' (the default) the slave will
#    still reply to client requests, possibly with out of date data, or the
#    data set may just be empty if this is the first synchronization.
#
# 2) if slave-serve-stale-data is set to 'no' the slave will reply with
#    an error "SYNC with master in progress" to all the kind of commands
#    but to INFO and SLAVEOF.
# slave-serve-stale-data yes
```

*in http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf*